# Xpath for text between sequential H2s?

Tags: html, xpath

I need to extract three sets of paragraph text beneath corresponding H2 headers ("Research Focus", "Past Experience" and "Education" - all separately). I see two challenges:

1. The text has no set number of paragraphs (ie. in the below example, "Research Focus" has 3 paragraphs beneath - but it may be 1, or 5.
2. Although I only need to extract one set of paragraph text beneath one corresponding H2 at a time, there are multiple sections of H2s and text nearby. That's why I'm referring to three here now.

I had tried using following-sibling, eg.

```
//*[.='Research Focus']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

... but that's obviously not right.

In other words:

1. What is the correct Xpath for the "Research Focus" text?
2. What is the correct Xpath for the "Past Experience" text?
3. What is the correct Xpath for the "Education" text?

Thank-you.

```
<div id="main-content-with-sidebar" class="col-sm-9">

  <h2>Research Focus</h2>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum urna neque, tincidunt id tincidunt ac, varius non felis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum urna neque, tincidunt id tincidunt ac, varius non felis.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>

    <h2>Past Experience</h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>

    <h2>Education</h2>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>

    <h2>List heading</h2>
    <ul class="staffBlogList">
        <li>List items I don’t need</li>
        <li>List items I don’t need</li>
        <li>List items I don’t need</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Another list heading</h2>
    <ul class="staffCitationList">
        <li>List items I don’t need</li>
        <li>List items I don’t need</li>
        <li>List items I don’t need</li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: What really a task - find h2 with p chilldren? Get h2 and p? Get only p?

Comment: You should explicitly show what you wish to select.  You also really should accept more than 2 of the many fine answers you've received to your previous 15 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1: '//h2[contains(., "Research Focus")]/following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::h2[contains(., "Research Focus")]]'

2: '//h2[contains(., "Past Experience")]/following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::h2[contains(., "Past Experience")]]'

3: '//h2[contains(., "Education")]/following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::h2[contains(., "Education")]]'
```

The idea is to first get the `h2` tag you want to then get the following h2, then get all the previous siblings until the `h2` tag you wanted.

Comment: thanks very much. That’s excellent.  
  
1. I’m going to try to unpack that…  
  
    `//h2[contains(., "Research Focus")]`  
  
^ starting point  
  
    `/following-sibling::h2[1]`  
  
^ end point, 1 being the first instance of a H2, not including the one we start with  
  
    `/preceding-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::h2[contains(., "Research Focus")]]`  
  
^ I know this gets my paragraphs, but I don’t know how

Comment: What if those headers weren’t contained in H2s but in `<p><strong><span>Research In Focus</span></strong></p>`, all <p>s at same level? Is there an Xpath that would accommodate both of these constructions?

Comment: just change h2 for span I think

Comment: I'm scraping from a set of web pages which may have the headers in H2, may have them in P/strong/span...it's either/or... is there a way to accommodate the uncertainty?

Comment: you should have created a question with that structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98293/discussion-between-robert-andrews-and-elrull).